# Send real time data from Simulink over ip network

Tags: python, matlab, networking, udp, simulink

I have a python script running continuously on a Raspberry Pi listening for a UDP message, which it will print if it receives.

The python code on the Pi is:

```
import socket
import os

UDP_IP = 10.42.0.100
UDP_PORT = 5004

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGARM)

sock.bind((UDPIP, UDP_PORT))

while True:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(2048)
    debugmessage = data[0:]
    print "Debug data ", debugmessage
```

This works fine if I use a similar python script on my PC which sends arbitrary data. But how do I send Simulink data in real time from my PC to the Raspbery Pi?

There are a few blocks in Simulink that claim to be able to do this: UDP send, TCP/IP send, send, etc.

I have tried them all with various data formats, but nothing seems to work. I am receiving no errors, but no data appears on the pi terminal like it does when I simply send from the python script running in the windows terminal.

I don't mind using some kind of work around, e.g, stream from simulink to matlab workspace, get data from matlab workspace in python code, then send over UDP with my currently working code. I've tried this but also couldn't get it working.

There a few slightly similar questions to this that have been asked on stack exchange, but none of them explicitly say what to do. I've been attempting this for days and starting to get desperate, so can somebody please tell me exactly how I can send data from Simulink in real time over an IP network?

Thanks!

Comment: I assume you have verified that the ip address and port are all set in the simulink block same as your python script?

Comment: Can you send and receive data using the loopback interface as described [here](http://de.mathworks.com/help/instrument/examples/basic-udp-communication.html)? What happens if you click the `Verify address and port connectivity`] in the [UDP Send Dialog](http://de.mathworks.com/help/instrument/udpsend.html)?

Comment: @navan yep, I either use the Pi ip or I set it to broadcast, i.e 255.255.255.255. If I click verify address it says that the address has been found and is usable.

Comment: @m.s Your link takes me to the UDP communication with the instrument control toolbox, which I have tried. But it doesn't say anything about a loopback interface (maybe because I'm on a mobile I'm getting a different site). What is loopback?

Comment: loopback = 127.0.0.1, this is just for testing if the data ever gets out of simulink

Comment: Cheers. I'll try this in the morning :)

Comment: @m.s. The example you gave works when I use the ip address 'localhost' or 127.0.0.1, as you suggested. The data gets out of simulink then returns to simulink. However, nothing is appearing on the pi terminal at 10.42.0.100 when I use this address. Does my python code in the original question need changing?

Comment: @Blue7  how you define UDP_PORT variable as 5004? How can i identify this port no?

Comment: @BirunthaGnaneswaran It's been a while since I was working on this, but I believe you can change the port by simply double clicking on the UDP send block in Simulink.
http://uk.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/udpsend.html